# Can't understand Firestore batch update - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What I understand after reading the Firestore official batch operations doc is that, Batch operations perform multiple operations and can change multiple documents simultaneously.

However, when I read the sample code in the official firestore doc for updates it says:

```
var sfRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});
```

Now, I don't understand why they gave the name of a specific document when trying to update the batch. I thought the whole point of batch operations was to update multiple documents in a collection, so why are we giving the name of the document and limiting the operation only to a single document.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, limit your self to a single question per post.  You have two distinct questions.  I'm going to answer the first one.  I strongly recommend you edit the question to remove the second question and ask it separately, so that the question doesn't get closed as "needs focus".  In your second question, you should explain what is wrong with the code you've written.  If it doesn't work, provide the error message, or explain what it doesn't that's different than what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I don't understand why they gave the name of a specific document when trying to update the batch.

It's required to call out each individual document to create, update, or remove in the batch.  There are no alternatives to this.  Firesotre doesn't offer any way to bulk update multiple items as a result of a query, similar to SQL "update where" queries.  If you have multiple items to update in a batch, you would instead have to:

1. Perform the query to find each document
2. Iterate the results and collect references to each document
3. Add each document update to the batch using the batch API.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question again Doug. I am fairly new to flutter and firestore and I feel totally lost. Do you think you might be able to give me a small snippet that could show me how the 3  steps are done?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You should be able to easily find documentation about each one of those tasks.  If you got as far as writing the batch update that you gave here, the rest should be easy.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, if you find an answer helpful, it's customary to upvote and mark answers as correct using the buttons to the left of the answer.